# Find number of combinations that satisfy 2 conditions

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

I ran into a math problem as follows:
In a room, there are 3 doctors and 7 nurses, 3 members of the group are picked, what is the probability that the team of 3 contains 1 doctor, 2 nurses and that one of the nurses is the tallest one.
What I did, was used 10C3 to see the total number of combinations of 10 people in a group of 3, giving me 120, then, I physically counted the number of cases where the 2 conditions mentioned above were satisfied, so the result was 18/120, or 3/20, which was correct.
However, I am wondering if there is a way to do this without physically having to write out all of the arrangements, perhaps using nCr again, or something else. Thank you!

Comment: You want the team to have the tallest nurse and one of the other $6$ nurses and one of the $3$ doctors.  ${1 \choose 1} { 7-1 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1} = 1\times 6 \times 3=18$

Comment: Hmm, interesting, so when we want to find the number of combinations that satisfy more than one condition, we find them individually and multiply them?

Comment: @PaperBro64 Not always. It depends on dependencies, so the order of "choosing" matters. For example, if you were to choose a random nurse from the seven as the first nurse (before taking the tallest nurse), there is the possibility that you chose the tallest nurse or you didn't. If you chose the tallest nurse, then you can choose any of the six remaining nurses as the second nurse. However, if you chose a different nurse, then your second choice for nurse must be the tallest nurse. 

If you instead choose the tallest nurse first, then the next nurse can be any of the remaining six.

Comment: We would still multiply the combinations in both cases though, wouldn't we?

Comment: Let's try: Step 1: Choose a random nurse from the seven. This can be done in $$_7C_1$$ ways. 

Step 2: If the chosen nurse is the tallest nurse, choose any of the remaining six nurses, but if the chosen nurse is not the tallest nurse, choose the tallest nurse. This can be done in ??? ways? These are not independent events, so the product principle does not apply. The first choice very much decides what choices are available for the second choice.

Comment: There are other approaches. For example, you can take the total number of ways to choose the three without restriction and subtract off the number of ways the restriction can be violated. For example, suppose we just choose one doctor and two nurses at random, then subtract where we choose one doctor and two nurses, but neither nurse is the tallest? That would be: $$(_7C_2)(_3C_1)-(_6C_2)(_3C_1) = 63-45=18$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\binom{3}{1} \times \binom{6}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}}. \tag1 $$

(1) above agrees with your computations and is explained as follows:

- First of all, you must be consistent in deciding whether order of selection of the $3$ people is deemed pertinent.  Since the denominator reflects combinations, rather than permutations, the numerator must also presume that order of selection is not pertinent.
- Then, to satisfy the constraint, the (presumably unique) tallest nurse must be included.  This means that the only options will revolve on which of the other $2$ people are selected.
- You will then have the choice of selecing $1$ person from the $3$ doctors, and $1$ person from the remaining $6$ nurses.